# Help in locating the URL rewrites in place for an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

First off i'll advise i'm not familiar with implementing url re writing on any level.

That said I do know there are 2 types or rewrites setup for this site.

One I can locate and is solely responsible for top level rewrites (turning .com to .co.uk)

There is another rewriter implemented somehow somewhere, very early on in a pages lifecycle and I cannot find how or where the site is doing this. It's possible it's all handled in a 3rd party DLL but I would like to know the steps I might go through to prove or disprove this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your web.config have registered in the httpModules section? Often URL Rewriters are registered very early in the request life cycle. httpModules and httpHandlers can grab the request here. This is of course assuming you've ruled out IIS redirects. After that you can look for manual redirection in the global.asax file. There are a lot of places to look when you don't know how the original coder decided to implement the idea. I've seen some bad places, including in the constructor of a common base page inherited by every page on the site.

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriters are typically ISAPI filters - you can search currently applicable ISAPI filters on Web Site or Folder properties in IIS 6 (you might have ISAPI filters in right context menu), on II7, ISAPI filters in features view when you select web site or folder.

With .NET 3.5 or 4.0, its possible that ASP.NET routing might be the reason - you can locate that in web.config or global.asax (common places for putting the routes).

Answer (score 0):

My word i'm so sorry after finally tracking down an original dev there is no re-writes whatsoever. The solution is complex but workable. Weird etc :).  Love IT.